# How to implement If else condition in MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to check the value present in two fields of the table and based on that I want to display either field 1 or field 2.
For Example:

```
Select name from users if address1='Mars' 
else select age from users if address2='Mars';
```

I want to achieve this using plane SQL because I need to implement this in the controller of Rails using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("sql query")`

What should be the SQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CASE`

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN address1='Mars' THEN name 
            WHEN address2='Mars' THEN age
        END
FROM    users
```

Comment: how to remove null values?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try `User.find_by_sql("your sql query")`